# SVG Image on Android in Genexus 17

Tags: genexus, genexus-sd

I'm using Genexus v17 u4 with Android Gen.

I'm trying to consume an API that returns an SVG image, but it doesn't work on Android SD. If I do it with an API that returns a PNG image, it works fine.

In this case, I need the SVG images because the API I want to consume only returns SVG images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, GeneXus (for Android/iOS) does not have support for svg images, but it is a feature that is currently being worked on, and will be available in future versions.

If you want to test it out, download the GeneXus Beta version from the download center.